# Getting "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myoutfile.csv' " error in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I am using this line to create a new file (the file does not exist):

```
with open(outfilename, 'rwb') as outfile:
```

And it gets this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myoutfile.csv'
```

I am trying to create this file, and I thought if I used 'w' that would create it if it doesn't exist. If it is permissions, how do I create a new folder and refer to its path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The open mode passed to the `open()` function accepts only a specific few combinations of letters. In your case, `'rwb'` is not one of those combinations, and Python is perhaps assuming that you meant `'rb'`. Try:

```
with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
```

This opens the file for writing. If you need to *both* write to *and* read from the same handle, use:

```
with open(outfilename, "w+b") as outfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain `rwb` isn't a valid mode for `open`. Depending on the behaviour desired, you may have to opt for one of `r+b` or `w+b`.

Use `rb` is you want to read an existing file.

Use `r+b` is you want to read/write an existing file.

Use `wb` is you want to write an existing or non-existing file (will truncate an existing file first).

Use `w+b` is you want to read/write an existing or non-existing file (will truncate an existing file first).

Use a combination if you don't want truncation of an existing file, something like (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
open with "r+b"
on error:
    open with "w+b"
```